# Get application context in MyFirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android

I need to call a worker method from my MyFirebaseMessagingService class which accepts context as a parameter. But I do not have access to the app context in MyFirebaseMessagingService. How can this be done?

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());


            MessageSender messageSender = new MessageSender();
            messageSender.sendMessage(CONTEXT HERE);

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                //scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                //handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`FirebaseMessagingService` extends `Service` and

`Service` extends `ContextWrapper` and

`ContextWrapper` extends `Context`

so it is a context as well, so use `MyFirebaseMessagingService.this` or simply `this`

Comment: This is no longer valid on firebase-messaging 17.3.3

Comment: @RandySugianto'Yuku' From the [Official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) it is still valid and implementation steps are still same.

Comment: i got `android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`